# java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /home/dataflair/hdata/dfs/name/current during Hadoop installation

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am installing hadoop . Everything went well but when i tried this command to format :

```
//Format the name node:
$bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

I got the following errors :

```
> 16/06/30 12:58:12 WARN namenode.NameNode: Encountered exception during
> format:  java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory
> /home/dataflair/hdata/dfs/name/current    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:334)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:546)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:567)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:148)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:930)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1368)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1493)
> 16/06/30 12:58:12 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory
> /home/dataflair/hdata/dfs/name/current    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:334)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:546)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:567)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:148)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:930)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1368)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1493)
> 16/06/30 12:58:12 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1 16/06/30
> 12:58:12 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
> /************************************************************
> SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at rahul-knoldus/127.0.1.1
> ************************************************************/
```

I have tried `sudo hdfs namenode -format`
but its not working .

Answer (score 0):

Following steps resolved my problem -

`sudo su`

`/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format`